# Fill Form Selenium Python, Receive Pop Up Message and clear filled with loop

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to loop through filling form with Selenium Python. So far I can fill the first form and get the popup message. What I want is to get the next element in the loop but It seems I can not clear the previous filled text.

Here is my code:

```
import time 
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


postnummer = [42435, 42448]
street_name =["Bredfjällsgatan", "Fjällviolen"]
street_number = [12, 5]


inputPost = '//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/a/form/input[1]'
inputStreet = '//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/a/form/input[2]'
inputNumber = '//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/a/form/input[3]'

submitButton = '//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/a/form/span[4]'
closeButton = '//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/a'

#result = '//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/p/text()[1]'


def sleep():
    time.sleep(3)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get("https://www.framtidensbredband.se/")

i = 0
while i < len(postnummer):
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(inputPost).send_keys(postnummer[i])
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(inputStreet).send_keys(street_name[i])
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(inputNumber).send_keys(street_number[i])
    sleep()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(submitButton).click()
    sleep()
    #print(browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".alertbox .message").text)
    elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='message']")
    print(elem.text)

    browser.find_element_by_xpath(closeButton).click()
    sleep()
    #browser.clear()
    #browser.find_element_by_xpath((inputPost).send_keys(postnummer[i])).clear()
    #browser.find_element_by_xpath((inputStreet).send_keys(street_name[i])).clear()
    #browser.find_element_by_xpath((inputNumber).send_keys(street_number[i])).clear()
    #sleep()

browser.quit()
```

I tried clear() but I think I am not using properly.

Scraping website: https://www.framtidensbredband.se/

[image: Result Image Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear the field you need to use `element.clear()` 
To iterate the loop and use next value you need to increment the counter.

**Code**:

```
i = 0
while i < len(postnummer):

    browser.find_element_by_xpath(inputPost).send_keys(postnummer[i])
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(inputStreet).send_keys(street_name[i])
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(inputNumber).send_keys(street_number[i])
    sleep()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(submitButton).click()
    sleep()

    elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='message']")
    print(elem.text)

    browser.find_element_by_xpath(closeButton).click()
    sleep()

    browser.find_element_by_xpath(inputPost).clear()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(inputStreet).clear()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(inputNumber).clear()
    sleep()
    i=i+1
```

Comment: Thanks. That works perfectly. I missed incrementing the loop and the same time clearing the values.